# Save Values to HTML5 localStorage -> populate on page load

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, local-storage

I am following the [example](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch05_id35816678.html) in the O'Reilly "Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS and Javascript,"  I want the values entered from a form to populate after the app closes and reloads, similar to a php 'sticky form.'

The only aspects I changed from the example is that saveSettings is called on submit, and here I have it called on unload (previously on input blur).

Load settings is called on document ready rather than submit.

EDIT I deleted the extra hash sign, i showed code with jquery included (it was included before) 
    I bound saveSettings to unload.  The values are still not sticky.  When I close the window and open it again they are gone

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#current-age').blur(saveSettings);
    loadSettings();
});
function loadSettings() {
    $('#monthly-income').val(localStorage.income);
    $('#saving-per-month').val(localStorage.saving);
    $('#current-age').val(localStorage.age);
}
function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.age = $('#current-age').val();
    localStorage.saving = $('#saving-per-month').val();
    localStorage.income = $('##monthly-income').val();
}             
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="content">   
    <div data-type="horizontal"  data-role="controlgroup">
        <a href="#foo"   data-role="button">Input</a>
        <a href="#foo1"  id="output-button" data-role="button">Output</a>
    </div>
    <input type="number" min="500" max="10000" step="100" name="monthly-income" id="monthly-income" value=""/>
    <input type="number"  min="500" max="10000" step="100" name="saving-per-month" id="saving-per-month" value=""/>
    <input type="number" min="16" max="75" step="1" name="current-age" id="current-age" value=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code block could use some proper formatting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your code work, you have to apply two changes:

- Include the jQUery framework. Example: 
  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css"></script>`
- Change **`localStorage.income = $('##monthly-income').val();`** to
  **`localStorage.income = $('#monthly-income').val();`** (=omit one sharp, `#`).

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fE7pC/**

Note: Instead of binding an event listener to `blur`, I recommend to bind it to `onload`, so that the settings are automatically saved when leaving the page:

```
$(window).unload(saveSettings);
```

Another note: jQuery mobile recommends `pageInit`, rather than `$().ready`. See: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: pageInit is saying "function not defined" it is not in this version of  JQuery Mobile for some reason.  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js

Comment: i mean this link, it's pageinit is not in here http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js

Comment: @alex_borsody `.live('pageInit', ...)`. The event should be fired by the mobile browser. It's not a jQuery-specific event.

Comment: how do you use the pageInit() event?  have a hard time finding any info ;(

Comment: @DanielMagnusson According to the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) (near the bottom), the `oageInit` event has to be bound to the page element using `$('#id-of-page').live('pageInit', function(ev) {/*Code here*/});`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the **DEMO** here:- **[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/zrsoc16s/)**

If you are using jQuery once, do not mix it by pure javascript, like `document.getElementById()`. And do not create a `height` variable to store the `$('#height').val()`, you can use this directly. Code is more readable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).unload(saveSettings);
    loadSettings();
});

function loadSettings() {
    $('#height').val(localStorage.height);
    $('#weight').val(localStorage.weight);
    $('#dateOfBirth').val(localStorage.dateOfBirth);
    $('input[value="' + localStorage.gender + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    $("#sportive").val(localStorage.sportive);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.height = $('#height').val();
    localStorage.weight = $('#weight').val();
    localStorage.dateOfBirth = $('#dateOfBirth').val();
    localStorage.sportive = $("#sportive").val();
    localStorage.gender = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
}
```